# SD Card not accessible with NO MEDIA ERROR

Tags: formatting, sd-card, media, file-corruption

I have a Sandisk 16GB MicroSD card, few days ago, the card suddenly stopped working, and this has happened before, the entire card was formatted or erased by itself back then, I had to reformat it and recover all my photos and files.

However, this time, while I was using my Android Phone the SD card vanished all of the sudden and I could not access it. I tried reinserting, restarting the phone etc.

When I connect the SD card to my Windows PC the OS cannot detect the memory card, there is no driver allocation to it.

The memory card reader has no fault, I confirmed with disk manager
[Disk Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ug9m.png)

I used the **chkdsk** function to check about the SD Card and the card was not accessible.

Check the image below: 
[chkdsk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLjcr.png)

Even disk manager of windows does not provide any useful information, just that the drive is not detected, the same, there is no media in it.

[disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPZPJ.png)

I even tried changing the driver letter but still there is no use.

The dskpart option shows that the sd card has no media in it and is of 0 bytes.
[dskpart vol info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfFum.png) and 
[dskpart detailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7wAL.png)

Please try to understand that this sd card contains a lot of my photos, my birthdays, farewall party everything. I utterly need them back. Please help me get through with this.

Comment: Please try to understand this 3 basic concepts about data preservation: Backup, backup and backup. Had you done that you wouldn't have that problem now. And if not done before, then at the very least when the SD card started showing issues. And there are many cloud solutions that would have enabled the automatic backup of photos and other media with a simple app in the Android phone. Honestly, there's no excuse not to do a cloud or local backup if the data is so important. Now, according to the reported problem, your SD card is as good as dead. Next time do your backups, one way or another.

Comment: I am in my examinations, and my phone storage and sd card storage are both full. I was gonna do that after I would finish my exams, but apparently the SD Card could not wait for that.

Comment: Install an Android app for cloud backup (e.g. Mega which has a generous 50GB for free) and setting it to automatically upload the photos: **Less than 2min** (because the actual backup is done automatically in the background); Connecting to phone to a PC with USB and backup locally: **Less than 5min** (YMMV and it depends on the supported USB speeds and the amount of data to be copied but once started there's nothing preventing the user to do other tasks).

Comment: On the bright side, take this as a lesson for life: If the data is valuable (even if only for emotional reasons) **always** backup!

Answer (score -1):

This is very common for flash storage devices. Either the memory controller dies or the flash memory is too damaged to be accessible from the OS. The only real way to even attempt to get the data back would be sending it off to a professional data recovery company (expect a $1,000+ bill)

As MichaelBay's comment mentioned, you should always backup and if you had a storage problem with the device at one point you should have got a new card and moved the photos over.

Comment: This is not helpful since a "professional data recovery company" use particular tools to recover the data. This answer should explain what tools they use, and how this could be accomplished.